# Calling JQuery script for the second time fails

Tags: jquery, html

I have called a jQuery function twice in the following code, but it only seems to work the first time.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
        />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
```

The following part works perfectly:

```
<p>Depature date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>
```

The next part produces the input text box, but doesn't have the image link to open the calendar option [it doesn't call the script]:

```
    <p>Depature date:
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    </p>**

    </body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated. I have a feeling this has a simply answer I just can't seem to see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make id into class.Id must be unique.Classes are groups.I have changed your code and pasted here..Use this it will work..

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
</script>

<p>Depature date:
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</p>


<p>Depature date:
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</p>
```

Mark as answer and give upvotes if the problem is solved.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this was the perfect answer. In addition to changing 'id' to class, I also needed to change "#datepicker' to ".datepicker". Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1):

id of element [should be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute), if you have multiple elements then use class attribute

```
<p>Depature date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /> 
</p> 
<p>Depature date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /> 
</p>**
```

Then

```
$(function() {
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true
 });
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y3tUq/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use multiple IDs on a single page. Use classes instead.

i.e.

```
<p>Depature date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
<p>Depature date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of id. You cant use multiple ids in an html page